# Dealing with 2 lists on activity?

Tags: android, list

I feel the answer is so obvious but im not noticing it, when I have 2 lists on an activity how do I control the onListItemClick void? so if I want 2 different lists for 2 different sets of information

Comment: can't you do list1.onListItemClick and list2.OnlistItermclick, defining two separate methods?

Comment: can not you use to set tag and then when you need your list you can get easily by using tag?

Comment: one of my lists were like this protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
  try {

   mp.reset();
   mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
   mp.prepare();
   mp.start();

  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
  }
 } what moficiations would  I have to make? @Gautham

Comment: Dont implement the interface, add the interface as a variable.

Comment: In that case, the id would be sufficient to identify the list right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should/can use the single `onItemClick` method for different `ListView` in same activity:

```
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {}
```

just once. You can then do something like `v.getId()` where `v` is `View` which will give you the id's of your `Listview` according to which you can handle the item click listener for more than one `ListView`:

```
v.getId();
```

and handle the item's click listener for the two `ListView's as below:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

        if( v.getId() == R.id.listView1 )
        {
           //Your logic for the first listview
        }
        else if( v.getId() == R.id.listView2 )
        {
           //Your logic for the second listview               
         }

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use two defferent method for listview ::->


 tasks_list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mapp=true;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Home_Activity.this,AddTask_Activity.class);
                    i.putExtra(DBAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, id);
                    Log.d("IDD", ""+id);

                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
            tasks_list1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mapp=true;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Home_Activity.this,AddTask_Activity.class);
                    i.putExtra(DBAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, id);
                    Log.d("IDD1", ""+id);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });
```